# Number of specific column values in consecutive rows of dataframe in R

Tags: r, count

Hello I have a quite large dataframe (~20k) with something like

`id | GroupID | action`
`1  | 1       | run`
`2  | 1       | walk`
`3  | 1       | rest`
`4  | 1       | run`
`5  | 1       | walk`
`6  | 2       | run`
`7  | 2       | walk`

I want to count the number off consecutive occurrences of action values ( for example (run,walk) which would be 3 in the above example. Also, would be good to be grouped by the groupID ( so 2 for group 1 and 1 for group 2 )

Is there any more nice way to do it except iterating row by row ?

Comment: Do you need it per id? Or just for the whole data set?

Comment: @DavidArenburg I updated the question. Would be nice to have it grouped by the group id

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a possible solution using `stringi` package

Select your vars

```
vars <- toString(c("run", "walk"))
```

Then

```
library(stringi)
aggregate(action ~ GroupID, df, function(x) stri_count_fixed(toString(x), vars))
#   GroupID action
# 1       1      2
# 2       2      1
```

Or similarly, combined with the `data.table` package

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, stri_count_fixed(toString(action), vars), by = GroupID]
#    GroupID V1
# 1:       1  2
# 2:       2  1
```

Basically we are converting `action` to a one long string separated by `,` and counting the occurrences of `"run, walk"` within each group.

Comment: It works! One more thing. Is there a way to dynamically name the 2 values ?

Comment: Thanks. I actually meant to specify each var, but I guess you can join them as strings with the comma separator.

Comment: You can pass them as a vector such as `c("run", "walk")` and then use `toString` on them.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `diff` function in `base`. This is assuming you only care about the run-walk combination, which is why rest was made an NA value. If errors arise in your actual data.frame, leave a comment so I may either adjust my answer or remove it.

```
> df<-data.frame(id=seq(1,7,1),
               group=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2),
               action=c('run','walk','rest','run','walk','run','walk'))
> df$value<-ifelse(df$action=='rest',NA,
                  ifelse(df$action=='run',1,2)

> df
  id group action value
1  1     1    run     1
2  2     1   walk     2
3  3     1   rest    NA
4  4     1    run     1
5  5     1   walk     2
6  6     2    run     1
7  7     2   walk     2

> setNames(aggregate(df$value,by=list(df$group),function(x) length(which(diff(x)==1))),c('group','run_walk'))
  group run_walk
1     1        2
2     2        1
```